# Race condition in Rhino DSL?

Tags: race-condition, boo, rhino-dsl

In my current project I am working with [Boo](https://github.com/bamboo/boo)/[Rhino DSL](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-dsl) (what a great thing(s) by the way).

In digging in the code I came across the following piece of code:

```
engine.Cache.WriteLock( () =>
{
    engine.Storage.NotifyOnChange(urls, delegate(string invalidatedUrl)
    {
         engine.Cache.Remove(invalidatedUrl);
         if (!standAloneCompilation.Contains(invalidatedUrl))
             standAloneCompilation.Add(invalidatedUrl);
    });
});
```

the intention here is pretty clear: the `engine.Cache` has to be protected from race condition when a url is removed from it. The problem I see here is that what is really protected is a call to the `Storage.NotifyOnChange` - not the `Cache.Remove`.

And all `NotifyOnChange` does is taking the supplied delegate and attach it as an event handler to the 'FileWatcher' it creates. So instead of protecting the `Cache.Remove` the write lock here protects creating the the FileWatcher, and leaves the `Cache.Remove` unprotected.

I have great respect to both Boo and Rhino, which makes me wonder - am missing something here? or the write lock should be really moved inside the delegate?

Here is the NotifyOnChange code if you are wondering:

```
    public virtual void NotifyOnChange(IEnumerable<string> urls, Action<string> action)
    {
        lock (pathToFileWatchers)
        {
            string[] commonPaths = GatherCommonPaths(urls);
            foreach (string path in commonPaths)
            {
                FileSystemWatcher watcher;
                if(pathToFileWatchers.TryGetValue(path, out watcher)==false)
                {
                    pathToFileWatchers[path] = watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path, FileNameFormat);
                    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                }
                watcher.Changed += delegate(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
                {
                    action(e.FullPath);
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, but I'd post it in the Rhino mailing list, where Ayende is more likely to see it: http://groups.google.com/group/rhino-tools-dev